# Data Extracting with talend

Tags: json, api, linkedin-api, talend, afabstractrestclient

I am trying to extact data from linkedin API using tRESTClient, tEXTRACTJSONFields and showing the output in the console with a tLogRow.

[image]

But when I run the job I get this error and its mostly related to the tRESTClient component.

[image]

But here is the configuration that I made for the tRESTClient [I added the url.

[image]

and I added the access token that I have

[image]

and the schema for response

[image]

and finally this advanced parameters

[image]

So please if any one can help me with it I will  be glad for you

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Add all relevant information directly to your question, as editable text

Comment: okey thank you but I really need  help with it

Comment: Hi I think that the issue comes from the schema of the output of the tRestClient, it's supposed to be (statusCode, body and string) but it seems that you modified it to name_seniority and id_seniority. This fieds are standard to the component and your schema is mean to be the output of the tExtractJSONFields

Comment: Hello Nawres , could you show us if you tested your api with postman for example , if you add the call of postman we will help you with correct configuration because for me your call is a little bit confusing uri?headers/relativepath seems a liitle ambigous for me . Just show us the call you are doing with postman ;)